# how to delete the file? I guess, maybe i am being invaded

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I want to delete the file '2915158693.shtml';
but the system shows:

> rm: cannot remove `2915158693.shtml': Operation not permitted.

How to delete the file?

```
[root]# lsattr ../ |grep 0721
----------I---- ../0721
[root]# lsattr 2915158693.shtml
--------------- 2915158693.shtml
[root]# id -u
0
[root]# rm 2915158693.shtml
rm: remove write-protected regular file `2915158693.shtml'? y
rm: cannot remove `2915158693.shtml': Operation not permitted
[root]#
```

Comment: Try `chmox 777 2915158693.shtml` first, then `rm`.

Answer (score 1):

`chmod 700 2915158693.shtml && chown root:root 2915158693.shtml` and then try removing it

Comment: thanky you sir，but  it shows operation not permitted and i am  the root

Answer (score 0):

Do this as root to remote file

```
#chattr -i 2915158693.shtml
#rm -f 2915158693.shtml
```

For more info [refer this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-delete-write-protected-file.html)